# Taking the option element in the head of the list

Tags: coq

I have type

```
Variable l: list (a * b * option c * option d).
Variable ls : list (list l).
```

I would like to take the type `option d` from the head of the list and check the whole list after that. My code look like this:

```
Definition test (l: list (a * b * option c * option d)):=
match l with
| nil => ... (* not important *)
| (_,_,_,od) :: l' => 
  match od with
  | None => ... (* not important *)
  | Some d => if forallb (fun li => forallb (fun ci => do_something ci d)) ls) l'
  end
end.
```

My question is that the testing `if forallb (fun li => forallb (fun ci =>do_something ci d))ls)l'` I added `forallb (fun li =>...)`because I would like it test in the whole list `l'`. But I did not use the argument `li`at all.

EDIT: My question focus on the `if forallb (fun li => forallb (fun ci => do_something ci d))ls)l'`. I added `forallb (fun li =>` because I would like to test on the rest of the list `l'`. Without `forallb (fun li` I can archive this test `if (forallb (fun ci => do_something ci d))ls` but I don't know how to test this condition again in the list `l'`.

Comment: What is `ls` in your definition? Why the inner `forallb`? It is very hard to help you as what you are trying to achieve is very unclear from your explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your context is inconsistent.

Variable l : ...

make that l is a list

Variable ls : list (list l).

assume that l is a type.

Maybe you meant:

Definition l := list (a * b * option c * option d).

Variable ls := list (list l).

This makes ls to be a list of list of lists (like a three-dimensional array).

Now, assuming that you meant do_something to have type l -> d -> bool

I guess you wanted to test do_something with all elements of type l in ls and all elements of type d in the argument of test (also called l, yuck).

you should have

...

|Some d => if forallb (fun li => forallb (fun ci => do_something ci d)) ls then test l' else false
...

But frankly, your question leaves to much for the answerer to guess!